# Using $\epsilon-\delta$-definition to prove the sign of $f$

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

**Theorem**:

If $f$ is continuous in $a\in D_f$ en $f(a)\ne 0$, then $f$ contains her sign in an environment around a.

**Proof**:

$\underline {f(a)\gt 0}:$ 
Take $\epsilon =\dfrac{f(a)}{2}$ then it guarantees the existence of a $\delta\gt 0$ so that

$$|x-a|\lt\delta\Rightarrow f(a)-f(x)\le |f(a)-f(x)|\le \dfrac{f(a)}{2}\qquad(1.1)
$$ 
$$\Longrightarrow |x-a|\lt\delta\Rightarrow 0\lt\dfrac{f(a)}{2}\lt f(x)\qquad (1.2) $$

> My following questions are:
>
> - Why does it say in step 1.2 f(a) -f(x) and not f(x)-f(a)? Because I'd think I'd take it over from the $\epsilon-\delta$-definition.
> - And is it correct to explain the step 1.1 to 1.2 as because $|f(a) -f(x)|= -f(a)+f(x)$ and $ f(a) -f(x)$ so that the second one cancels the left side of the inequality at step 1.1?

P.S.:

I know I left the second case $f(a)\lt 0$ out of it but it's analoguous to the former case. The only thing you have to replace is that $\epsilon=\dfrac{-f(a)} {2}$ and alter the inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the definition of the absolute value, $(1.1)$ could be rewritten as :

$$ |x-a| <\delta \Rightarrow f(x)\in \left[ \frac{f(a)}{2} , \frac{3\,f(a)}{2}\right]$$

My advice would just be to forget $ f(a) -f(x)$ and just work with $|f(a) -f(x)|$

---

However, you cannot assume you know the sign of $f(a)-f(x)$ as supposed in yous second point. You have to work with the absolute value instead.

That would allow you to write $-\epsilon<f(a) -f(x)<\epsilon$ or $-\epsilon<f(x) -f(a)<\epsilon$ (your choice) in order to prove $(1.2)$

Comment: But why is |f(a)-f(x)| and not |f(x)-f(a)| just like in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-defintion? I had already found that by the way.

Comment: There is no reason, both are interchangeable, why would that be a problem ? If you want to write it that way, I'm not going to fault you for writing $|a-b|$ instead of $|b-a|$

Comment: Oké, I just have a history of small detailed mistakes. And I'd like to avoid them.

Comment: In this case, as in most in this field, you are dealing with distances. $|f(x)-f(a)|$ is of course the result of the operations, but you should probably view it as the distance between two points

Comment: Ok, thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

If $|u-v|< \epsilon$, then $u-v< \epsilon$ and $v-u< \epsilon$.

Can you take it from here ?

Comment: That's what I said, right? I maybe have to change the disjunction 'or'.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: So there could stand f(x) -f(a)? So it would become $f(x)-f(a)\lt |f(x)-f(a)|\lt\dfrac{f(a)}{2}$.